# I can run Prestashop in docker-compose but I can't connect with mysql. Why?

Tags: php, docker, prestashop

I have this docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: prestashop
      MYSQL_USER: prestashop
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: prestashop
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - prestanetwork

  prestashop:
    image: prestashop/prestashop:1.7
    container_name: prestashop
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_SERVER: db
      DB_NAME: prestashop
      DB_USER: prestashop
      DB_PASSWD: prestashop
      PS_MODE_DEV: "1"
      COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER: 1
    ports:
      - "8008:80"
    volumes:
      - ./prestashop:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - prestanetwork

volumes:
  db_data:

networks:
  prestanetwork:
```

Mysql and Presta runs after docker-compose up and presta works but I can't connect with db with this data:
server: db,
user, name and password: prestashop
Do you know why?

Comment: You can't connect yourself (as host) to docker db? Or prestahop service cannot connect to db? Be more specific.

Comment: I can start prestashop and Docker ps display mysql but if I try install that, prestashop show error with connections.